# Is there a way for Angular data table not to display the data until the user key in same thing in the search button

Tags: angular

What I want is display is the picture below when the page load.

[image]

Comment: Simply don't bind data with table until user search something.

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have a example how to do it?